# Fancy box with mvc partial view issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, fancybox

This is the message I get everytime I click the edit button:
 The requested content cannot be loaded.
          Please try again later.

Anyone have any ideas? If you need to see the partial view I can post it.

My Conbtroller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SearchEdit(int modelcount)
    {

        using (Offers.OffersClient o = new Offers.OffersClient())
        {
            var offers = (List<Offers.Offer>)Session["offer"];
            var offer = offers[modelcount];

            return PartialView("Search_Edit", offer);
        }
    }
```

My View:

```
<div class="offer_edit">
    <a href="@Url.Action("SearchEdit","Home",null,"http")?modelcount=@(i)" class="fancybox">
        <img title="Edit" src="../images/edit_button.png" />
    </a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Either 1. the url you put in the html there doesn't work 2. you're initializing fancybox wrong... Please add the code used to initialize fancybox and please include the generated html.

Answer (score 0):

Your action is decorated with the `[HttpPost]` attribute. This means that this controller action can only be invoked using the POST verb. But in your view you are using a link (`<a>`) which when clicked sends a GET request unless you have configured the fancybox to use POST. To further investigate the issue you could use a javascript debugging tool such as FireBug to inspect the AJAX request being sent to the server as well as the response.